# Android SearchView Filter ListView

Tags: android, searchview

I have implemented Search Filter to my SearchView in my SherlockAction Bar.

When i type m i want to show filtered results in the list view below which only starts with M and so on. But now it shows random results.

[image]
[image]

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange");

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter("");
        Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange Empty String");
        placesListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange " + newText.toString());
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextSubmit");
    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {
    Log.i("Nomad", "onClose");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Place this inside your adapter:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter(){
   return new Filter(){

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
             constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
             FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                  List<String> founded = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(YourListItemType item: origData){
                            if(item.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                                founded.add(item);
                            }
                    }

                        result.values = founded;
                        result.count = founded.size();
                    }else {
                        result.values = origData;
                        result.count = origData.size();
                    }
            return result;


    }
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
           clear();
           for (String item : (List<String>) results.values) {
                 add(item);
           }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    }
    }
```

And this inside constructor of your adapter

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] places) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;

        this.data = Arrays.asList(places);
        this.origData = new ArrayList<String>(this.data);

 }
```

Comment: also i want to make sure the text it filters is of a particulat text only only. i think some of ur code is missing or its not formatted. can you please edit u answer

Comment: i just noticed u are using a Array Object but am passing a string Array into my Adapter. So all i need to do it convert the object into string

Comment: Yes, YourListItemType - means that you can place there whatever you want

Comment: nope. my constructor is like this public PlacesListAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] places)

Comment: this.data = Arrays.asList(places); - this will do the job. Edited my ansver

Comment: Thank you. i took your code as reference and implemented my version of it. When i type in some letter i am getting an error. updated my code

Comment: rolled back the question and posted it as a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040364/android-indexoutofboundsexception-error-for-search-filtering-list-view

Comment: i m getting this error The method add(String) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Place)

Comment: Sharing  a Gist with the code where i am calling the Adapter as well https://gist.github.com/4380422

Comment: you should ovverride add() in adapter method with your type

Comment: Greensy, overriding add() in arrayadapter is not necessary if you parameterize ArrayAdapter with "extends ArrayAdapter<YourItemType>". Also, your code doesn't work well with deleted chars in filterbox unless you delete all chars. So my suggestion would be to do "for (YourListItemType item: origData)" instead of "for (YourListItemType item: data)" as data is modified by the filtering-process.

Comment: @arne.jans thanks for your tip, i edited my code a bit)

Comment: i want to use this code, but what is `origData` in your answer?

Comment: add() and clear(); method calls I didn't understand.

Answer (score 6):

Get the filter from the adapter and filter vy the string changed in the seachview field on query changed.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            getListAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What should I do when the list gets emptied rather than filtered?

Comment: I guess it depends the effect you want to achieve, maybe hide it until you have content filtered to show

Comment: what's getListAdapter() ? i have `ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);`  and when i change `getListAdapter()` with `arrayAdapter`  i got this error `non static method cannot be referenced from a static context`  really hope you can help, i was searching for ours to make a simple search in listview in fragment without success

Answer (score 1):

Add the element in listview_arr and rest code is below...:-

```
    listview_arr = new String[listview_array_location.length];
    listview_arr = listview_array;

    setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));


    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
              // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count)
        {
            /*Log.d("count","count==>"+s.length());

                if(((s.length()-temp)%4)==0)
                {
                    Log.d("in if","if in if"+(s.length()-temp));
                    et.setText(et.getText().toString()+" ");
                    int position = et.getText().toString().length();
                    Editable etext = et.getText();
                    Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
                    temp++;
                }*/

            Log.d("count","count==>"+s);
            textlength = et.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < listview_array_location.length; i++)
            {
                if (textlength <= listview_array_location[i].length())
                {
                    if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)listview_array_location[i].subSequence(0,textlength)))
                    {
                        array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
                    }
                  }
            }
            AppendList(array_sort);
        }
    });
}

public void AppendList(ArrayList<String> str)
{
    listview_arr = new String[str.size()];
    listview_arr = str.toArray(listview_arr);

    setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
}

public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Activity cntx;
    public bsAdapter(Activity context)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cntx=context;

    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listview_arr.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listview_arr[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listview_array.length;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row=null;

        LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);

        TextView tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button Btn01=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.Btn01);
        Button Btn02=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.Btn02);

        tv.setText(listview_arr[position]);

        Btn01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(SearchUser.this, "Button 1 "+listview_arr[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                          SearchUser.this).getInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, Color.WHITE);
                  new ColorPickerDialog(SearchUser.this, SearchUser.this, color).show();
            }
         });

        Btn02.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(SearchUser.this, "Button 2 "+listview_arr[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });

    return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply go through this [example](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/). it is very easy to integrate in your application

Here is the logic with array and `addTextChangedListener` for EditText