# Android IndexOutOfBoundsException error for Search Filtering List View

Tags: android, searchview

I have implemented Search Filter to my SearchView in my SherlockAction Bar. 
I have Implemented a Custom Filter. When i type any letter i am getting an error

```
public class PlacesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place> implements
        Filterable {

    public Context mContext;

    List<Place> mPlaces, orig;

    public PlacesListAdapter(Context context, List<Place> places) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_places, places);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mPlaces = places;
        this.mContext = context;

        orig = new ArrayList<Place>(places);

    }

    @Override
    public Place getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mPlaces.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflater;
            viewInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_places, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.placeTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_title);
            holder.placeDistance = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_distance);
            holder.placeCategoryIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_category_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.placeTitle.setText(mPlaces.get(position).getPlaceName());
        holder.placeDistance.setText(mPlaces.get(position).getPlaceDistance());
        holder.placeCategoryIcon
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_category_hillstation);

        // // Setting Alternative Row Colors
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            convertView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_view_places_row_1);
        } else {
            convertView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_view_places_row_2);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView placeId;

        TextView placeTitle;

        TextView placeDistance;

        ImageView placeCategoryIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new PlaceFilter();
    }

    private class PlaceFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint){
            FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Place> results = new ArrayList<Place>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = mPlaces;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (Place g : orig) {
                        if (g.getPlaceName()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            mPlaces = (ArrayList<Place>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

**ERROR**

```
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at com.m7.nomad.PlacesListAdapter.getView(PlacesListAdapter.java:68)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2193)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1774)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1603)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2044)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1628)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2585)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-26 17:24:43.900: E/AndroidRuntime(18693):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Error**

Its pointing to

```
holder.placeTitle.setText(mPlaces.get(position).getPlaceName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug, you'll see that `mPlaces.getSize()` equals 1, and trying to access the item in position 1, you'll get an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception.

there is something wrong in your ArrayList and it probably doesn't have all the data you are trying to get.

Comment: where should i start looking into debuging ? the list is populated right on load. it only happens when i trying to type in and filter it

Comment: try putting a breakpoint at the beginning of `getView` and see where it takes you

Comment: when i type something - it directly goest to no results. http://pastebin.com/7q4dQC4B weird :(

Comment: I would make sure that in the constructor, the `mPlaces.size()` is lager than 1, and then debug the `getView` and see what goes wrong.

Comment: also, after looking at your pastebin edits, I noticed that you no longer compare the constraint to g.getPlaceName(), which was the intent in the original post, so it should be item.getPlaceName() if you were following the same data model..thanks for your posting all this!

Answer (score 2):

**Try to cover this line**

```
holder.placeTitle.setText(mPlaces.get(position).getPlaceName());
```

****with following condition ****

```
if(position < mPlaces.size() && holder.placeTitle != null)
  holder.placeTitle.setText(mPlaces.get(position).getPlaceName());
```

**EDIT :**

Here is my small implemented snippet:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater viewInflater;
                viewInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                // Try here first
                holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            }

            // Try here second
            // holder.textview = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            // holder.imageview = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

            if (holder.textview != null && position < data_text.length)
                holder.textview.setText(data_text[position]);
            if (holder.imageview != null && position < data_image.length)
                holder.imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

            return convertView;
        }
```

You can replace it with your variables.

Thanks.

Comment: i tried that. but now i am geting multiple enteries of the rows in random orders

Comment: @HarshaMV try to take out such declarations `holder.placeTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.place_title);` from `if` to `else` part in `getView` method. And if that will not work then put out side after `if..else`.

Comment: didnt get you. can you please explain

Comment: @HarshaMV see the edited solution I have posted. I have shown which places are good to declare holder controls.

Comment: yeah. i had missed out getCount method. just added it and its working :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your apps,

```
if (g.getPlaceName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
    results.add(g);
}
```

Comment: i want to use in particular .startsWith

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the code for a SearchView in a custom action bar that goes into your activity (or in this case a ListFragment), here it is:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_bar);
    SearchView groupSV = (SearchView)actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.groupSV);
    groupSV.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onQueryTextChange");
            ListViewFragment.adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onQueryTextSubmit");
            //ListViewFragment.adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

You will need to declare your adapter as static like this in your ListViewFragment:

```
public static ArrayAdapter<Your_obj> adapter = null;

public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    //...//
}
```

**Also, make sure to check out the OP's editted code from his link:**  [PASTEBIN EDITS](http://pastebin.com/7q4dQC4B)