# Android list -- how to find the wanted item?

Tags: android, android-widget

I do have a list of possibly several thousands items (just testing with shorter list with about 200 items). The information is stored in SQLite, the `ContentProvider`, loader and `SimpleCursorAdapter` is used. The list is sorted lexicographically, and the `android:fastScrollEnabled` is used. The list scrolls smoothly -- no problem when one knows the exact name of the item.

Occasionally, I would like to find the items that contain some substring somewhere in the middle of their name. The `... LIKE "%wanted%" is a solution for me. However, I would like to give the user an incremental filtering -- i.e. the list content be updated during typing the substring. The reasoning is that it may not be neccessary to type many characters, and one should find the item as soon as possible. The goal is not to find one or none item. The goal is to filter the list so that manual scrolling be acceptable to overview the candidate items and select one of them by touch.

I have met the `SearchView` widget that looks nicely at the action bar. Anyway, reading something more about it in the doc, I am not sure if it is the right tool for me. Or if the recommended implementation is the one for me. (I am an android beginner, I am even not sure if I understand it well.)

Is it possible to use the widget for incremental filtering of the list in the same activity that has the SearchView in the Action Bar? Can you point me to some code that possibly shows how to implement the wanted behaviour?

Comment: Try this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview

Comment: @AbhishekSabbarwal: Thanks. Please, formulate the short answer on OnQueryTextListener... and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code to try out :

```
public class AndroidListViewFilterActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();

    } 

    private void displayListView() {

       //Array list of countries
       List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
       countryList.add("Aruba");
       countryList.add("Anguilla");
       countryList.add("Netherlands Antilles");
       countryList.add("Antigua and Barbuda");
       countryList.add("Bahamas");
       countryList.add("Belize");
       countryList.add("Bermuda");
       countryList.add("Barbados");
       countryList.add("Canada");
       countryList.add("Costa Rica");
       countryList.add("Cuba");
       countryList.add("Cayman Islands");
       countryList.add("Dominica");
       countryList.add("Dominican Republic");
       countryList.add("Guadeloupe");
       countryList.add("Grenada");

      //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
      dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.country_list, countryList);
      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      // Assign adapter to ListView
      listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

      //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
      listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
         // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });

      EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
      myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
      }
     });
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have learned that the adapter must be filterable, which also holds for the `SimpleCursorAdapter` that I use. Isn't it easier simply to `.restartLoader` with the selection condition instead of fidling with `.filter`?