# SearchView in action bar

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview

I have an ArrayList with data fetched from a SQLite Database. that ArrayList is added to a ListView through an ArrayAdapter.it works. The problem is when I filter the list with a SearchView. It not works.
here my code:

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {


List<InforTask> list =new ArrayList<InforTask>();
ListAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
Menu mnOption = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    list = dbHelp.getAllInfor();
    adapter = new ListAdapter(ListActivity.this,R.layout.view_list_item,list);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}   


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mnOption = menu;
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView
            .setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());

                    return false;
                }
            });


    return true;
}
```

}
//

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search..."/>
```

Comment: 'It not works' is not enough to go on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview

Comment: Please refer [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/).

Comment: maybe adapter.notifyDataSetChange() ?

Comment: tks all. I modified my code and was able to get it to work.I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function