# access to search edit text in action bar using appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Hi i want to set listener to search edit text in android 2.3 for that i'm using appcompat.
my contact_menu.xml is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_search"
    />
```

my actionbar_search.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_menu, menu);

            View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

            //** Get the edit text from the action view *
            EditText txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.search);

            //** Setting an action listener *
            txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Search : " + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        return true;
    }
```

problem is when i run it in android 2.3 emulator i'm giving this error message

```
     11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.getActionView
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.rad.sarinab.contacts.onCreateOptionsMenu(contacts.java:172)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2158)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:70)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-17 07:31:05.893: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE**
after some research and useful comment by @blubrain and of course [this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25533235/is-it-possible-to-display-an-edittext-widget-on-the-action-bar-without-inflating)  i reach to this code:

my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:sarinaB="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        sarinaB:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        sarinaB:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        sarinaB:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

my oncreateoptionmenu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_menu, menu); 
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dddddd "+text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sssssss "+text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });


    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from android [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

```
If supporting API levels lower than 11:
- import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
If supporting only API level 11 and higher:
- import android.app.ActionBar
```

Make sure you are importing right actionbar, and please read [the document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Secondly make sure you are calling right methods. For 2.3 you have to call

```
MenuItemCompat.getActionView()
```

For further explanation: check [this part of the document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView).

So the line

```
View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

should be

```
View v = (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

Comment: thank you @bluebrain i chenge my code but now im getting this error    java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at com.rad.sarinab.contacts.onCreateOptionsMenu(contacts.java:174)

Comment: that error refer to  txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener do you know why?

Comment: @max I am not sure check this on document:       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);