# Include only person-based contacts when querying ContactsContract.Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a SearchView in which if I type a name, it shows a autocomplete list of names matching it. However contacts like **Facebook** **ambulance** and **AL Cricket** also come in these results. How to **exclude** such results and only get those contacts that are of actual people?

Code I am using to get display name is this :

```
  private String getDisplayNameForContact(Intent intent) {
    Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
    phoneCursor.moveToFirst();
    int idDisplayName = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    String name = phoneCursor.getString(idDisplayName);
    phoneCursor.close();
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selection and selection arguments to your `contentResolver.query`.

The arguments you want are:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"1"};
```

You add them like so:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Cursor contactsCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
```

The constant `ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` determines what subgroup of contacts you are querying.

Comment: What are you passing to the function via the intent?

Comment: I have a searchView... in that if i type a.. it shows all contacts with a, if i type af.. similarly, so it is essentially for autocomplete.. that is the data I am passing thru the intent

Comment: It sounds like you might be implementing search in an irregular pattern. If you want this to happen quickly, as the user types, you shouldn't be making a query every time something changes. This will be too slow.
You should query the list of contacts 1 time and then implement a filter.

See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview

You don't need to use an intent to send data to a function. Intents are for sending data between system elements such as apps, activities, or fragments.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, when you call - query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null) - get all list data. Where is null, theare is your selections parameters. It remains only to choose the appropriate options. Try my example, and swith different values (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SomethingElse).

I hope this helps.

```
private static Cursor allContactsQuery(Context context) {
    final String[] CONTACTS = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };

    String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY +
            "<>''" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1" +
            " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
    final String[] SELECTION_ARGS = null;
    final String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY;

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            CONTACTS,
            SELECTION,
            SELECTION_ARGS,
            SORT_ORDER);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: What is the filter for excluding non-people based contacts?

Comment: When you use  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone -. it means take only user contact list. But I'm not sure exactly. Because another clients programm have permission to add changes into ContentManager.

Comment: you should try only getting contacts with phone number