# Unable to filter listview items

Tags: android, baseadapter, searchview, android-filterable

I am trying to list all the installed applications and filter the result in the list view dynamically.  below is my code in the listadapter.java:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


   List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    List<PackageInfo> filteredData = null;
    List<PackageInfo> originalData = null;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    private boolean notifyChanged = true;
    ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public Listadapter(Activity context,  List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                       PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
        this.packageManager = packageManager;


        this.filteredData = packageList;
        this.originalData = packageList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }




    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if(filteredData==null){
            Log.v("LOG", "Warn, null filteredData");
            return 0;
        }else{
            return filteredData.size();
        }
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }



    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           // holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView
             //       .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy-MM-dd]");


        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
        //String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;

        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString() + "\n" + sdf.format(new Date(packageInfo.firstInstallTime));
       // String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
         //              packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString()+ "\n" + packageInfo.packageName ;

                appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 150);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
       // holder.apkName.setText(packageName);
      //  holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

      //  if (itemChecked[position])
       //     holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
       // else
         //   holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
/*
        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.ck1.isChecked())
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                else
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
            }
        });

        if (itemChecked != null) {

        }
*/
        return convertView;

    }

    //////search filter

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<PackageInfo> list = originalData;

            int count = packageList.size();
            final ArrayList<PackageInfo> nlist = new ArrayList<>(count);

            PackageInfo filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            packageList = (ArrayList<PackageInfo>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


    ///filter finished


}
```

In the MainActivity.java, I have below code to act on the Searchview inside OnCreate:

```
final Listadapter Adapter = new Listadapter(this, (ArrayList<PackageInfo>) packageList1, packageManager);

        apps.setAdapter(Adapter);


        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
        apps.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       final SearchView sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);



        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

                Adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

On entering text in SearchView, it does nothing. It does not filter the list view items or gives any error.

Comment: is it actionbar menu searchview  or separate view insdie activity ?

Comment: have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview/14038461#14038461 ?

Comment: It is a separate view inside activity layout i.e                                     <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:queryHint="Search...."


        />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using three arraylist. two is enough. remove packageList

you are returning the true for OnQueryTextSubmit.

```
 searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                    if (adapter != null && newText != null) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }


            });
```

and you are not comparing appname with searchtext  and not giving results to listview.

```
@Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String constraintStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

            if (constraintStr != null & constraintStr.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<PackageInfo> filterItems = new ArrayList< PackageInfo>();

                synchronized (this) {
                    for (PackageInfo item : originalData) {
                        if (packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
             item.applicationInfo).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraintStr)) {
                            filterItems.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    result.count = filterItems.size();
                    result.values = filterItems;
                }
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.count = originalData.size();
                    result.values = originalData;
                }
            }
            return result;


        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<PackageInfo>) results.values;

            // Debug.e("filteredData", "" + filteredData.toString());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sree Reddy Menon. Now, I am able to filter the list view items properly. A quick question, if I want to add the filtered item into an array when clicked on it, how can I get its package name? With get(int), it is getting the original items at the respective positions, but I want the filtered item.

Comment: I didnt get you. You want filtered items  or selected item from Listview when clicking on Listview. ?

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I have achieved what I was looking for i.e select filtered items correctly. Many thanks for your help :-)