# Using a space key in searchview to filter a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview, space

I have succeeded to implement a searchview to filter in real time my ListView except the searchview doesn't accept to type a keywords containing a key space...

If I'm typing "Test", all my row that contain "Test" are appearing but if I type "Test number", nothing appear even if there are a few match in my ListView.

I found two posts that treat similar problems but even after I read it, I do not understand from where this issue come from.

Do you know how to solve this ?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.persmenu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

EDIT : the problem seems different than what I was thinking. The space key is taken into account but the dapter.getFilter().filter(newText) doesn't seems to filter all the textview by the same way.
It applied the query on the 1 textview of the filter. If i'm putting the content of the second textview of the adapter in the 1 textview, the query is working and I find the right information.
So, know, I need to understand why the filter applied in the adapter but only in the first textview and not in all...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview

Comment: That's a different issue. In this post, he wants to only filter the list by the first letter of the searchview. Here I'm trying to use my filter with multiple word separate with a space.

Comment: Make it list item and query string also lowercase.. I think  it will work fine...