# Can we make a search filter for listview without using a Model?

Tags: android

First off, this is a simple activity that was given to us from our university professor. I have tried creating a search filter for listviews but haven't tried without the use of a Model and a Custom Adapter.

Is it possible to create a search filter without using a Model and a Custom Adapter?

Comment: Android has its own Adapter but to add Search Filter in Listview you shoud go with Vustom Adapter and Model. Without Model you can also archive this but for ccurate result i prefer to use model also

Comment: yes its possible to achieve search filter without model and a custom adapter.

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati how? Do you have a reference link?

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo no i haven't any link. but when user search you have to change arraylist as per search result and then notify that adapter.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo got it or still not ?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview

Comment: or alternatively this : https://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati okay I got it

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo ok so if i write answer so can you upvote it or not ?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati if it works, I always upvote answers that works

Comment: @Beverly Castillo so it's working or still not ?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati I am about to try it but my professor added another functionality on the app and suddenly decided to use a model

Comment: @Beverly Castillo so you are collage student. That's great if you professor is look into your project and guide you regarding project